# Layout is not set as expected after adding rule to Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

This is my layout xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMenuContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frgMenu"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.narola.fragments.MenuFragment" />
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHomeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.narola.fragments.HeaderFragment" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frgHeader"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result for above xml:

[image]

now this above layout I setting the `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutMenuContainer"` property for relative layout (`android:id="@+id/layoutHomeContainer"`) instead of parent top :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMenuContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgMenu"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.narola.fragments.MenuFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHomeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutMenuContainer">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.narola.fragments.HeaderFragment" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frgHeader"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

the result is :

[image]

instead of slide down the right view it is crunching the view in its parent layout . why this is happen ? and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please explain this line ? "instead of slide down the right view it is crunching the view in its parent layout"

Comment: means the right layout width is match the boundary  as you can see in the layout what i want is dont want to change the width just the x position of the right view.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you should try using  `android:layout_marginRight="20dp"` in your RelativeLayout . Here 20dp is for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the width of parent relative layout from match parent to wrap content.